# relative numbers neovim, number colors

Tags: neovim

[image]

I'm trying to add realtive numbers to neovim the only thing I can find is regarding to vim which is "set relativenumber" which doesn't work in my init.lua. Not only that, but I'm trying to change the numbers to be white? How would I go about fixing this

Comment: Do you still have the problem? Is the answer not providing the information you need?

Comment: i'm so sorry I kinda went into a slight depressive mode for like a week for the first time in my life due to the stress of college accpetance so haven't even thought about neovim, but yes you helped immensely I thank you very much

Comment: Take care, mental health is super important :-) If the answer is solving your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest too :-)

Comment: I appreciate that very much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have relative number in Lua you have to:

```lua
vim.opt.relativenumber = true
```

You can control the color of the Line Number by changing the highlighting group:

- `LineNr` and
- `CursorLineNr` and optionally
- `LineNrAbove`
- `LineNrBelow`

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'LineNr', { fg = "white"})
```

You can get the complete list of highlighting group using the `hi` command.

Remark: If you like to have it in a buffer you can use the [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin and use the `Verbose hi` command.